# What are some good WWSAPI information sources?

Tags: soap, native, wwsapi

Does anyone have some good suggestions for sites, books, tutorials or other information sources on WWSAPI and its use?

I'm being dropped in the deep end on a project using it and want to bring myself up to speed.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/magazine/ee335693.aspx has been the main source of my knowledge so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the collection of pages I ended up forming.

**A good introductory article:**

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/magazine/ee335693.aspx

**Introductory demo:**

- http://msmvps.com/blogs/angelhernandez/archive/2009/09/28/wwsapi-windows-web-services-api-interop-wpf-cool.aspx

**Blogs on WWSAPI** (both seemingly dead, but contain a fair bit of useful information):

- http://blogs.msdn.com/nikolad/default.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/haoxu/default.aspx

**WWSAPI Home page:**

- http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wwsapi

**MSDN documentation:**

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd430435(VS.85).aspx

**Link compilation of WWSAPI information:**

- http://blogs.msdn.com/nikolad/pages/connecting-c-c-and-web-services.aspx

**Using WWSAPI Tracing:**

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751795.aspx