# WWSAPI and setting "soapenv:Header" values

Tags: soap, header, soapheader, wwsapi

I'm trying to connect to a web service from a C++ app using WWS.  I got the base connection working just fine.  My XML message has two parts though, a header (soapenv:Header) and a body (soapenv:Body).  the generated functions only fill in the body.  How do I set the Header information?  I assumed it has something to do with WsSetHeader() or WsAddCustomHeader() but can't seam to find the right values to use in the parameters.  Can someone point me in the right direction here?

I've been googling and trying to research this now for several days and am finding many sources for basic help with WWSAPI, but nothing seams to go deeper into how to use it for more advanced applications.  any good links or resources to find more advanced help on WWSAPI?

Thanks,

--Ben Burnett

[www.burnett.ws](http://www.burnett.ws/)

Answer (score 0):

[This example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) contains information on adding a custom header, but reading your description it is ambiguous whether you want the standard message headers or custom headers.  If you are actually talking about the standard message headers, then these should be populated by [WsCreateMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd430501%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [WsInitializeMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd430568%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2099530/what-are-some-good-wwsapi-information-sources has an answer that contains some information sources on WWSAPI as well.